# How to test Comparator using Junit Test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, comparator

Assuming i do not change the current way of my compare method, how can i create a test for this properly? I am struggling to understand how.

I need to test the below:

```
public class MemberComparator implements Comparator<Member> {

private final String clientId;

public MemberComparator(String clientId) {
    this.clientId = clientId;
}

@Override
public int compare(Member m1, Member m2) {
    if (m1.getClientId().startsWith(clientId)) {
        return m2.getClientId().startsWith(clientId) ? m1.getClientId().compareTo(m2.getClientId())
                : -1;
    } else {
        return m2.getClientId().startsWith(clientId) ? 1
                : m1.getClientId().compareTo(m2.getClientId());
    }
}
```

}

So far i have created this test, but i get an error. Can someone show how i can get this to work?

```
class MemberComparatorTest {

//private MemberComparator caseID_test;
private final MemberComparator memberComparator = new MemberComparator("jake");

@Test
void testEqual() {
    Member m1 = new Member();
    Member m2 = new Member();
    int result = memberComparator.compare(m1,m2);
    //assertTrue("expected to be equal", result == 0);

}
```

}

Comment: What is the default `clientId` when a new `Member` is instantiated? Without knowing that it's hard to tell how it's supposed to compare

Comment: Please edit your previous question to add details rather than asking the modified question again.

Comment: @AndyTurner Okay will do.